# Regex to find and replace string starting and ending text in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

How can I regex to find and replace string starting with (e.g.) "AB" and ending with "ZX" in Swift 2.x?

Edit: I wanna keep between AB and ZX string. e.g.

```
first situation: AB_asdad_ZX 
second situation: _asdad_
```

(I want to replace with empty string ("") but keeping between AB and ZX)

Comment: Do you want to replace the whole string, the ends, the middle, something else? Would a non-regex solution also work for you? Is the string in an array, in the middle of text, or some other place?

Comment: What have you tried? I suggest searching online on "anchored" regular expressions and capture groups. It takes a little study to figure it out.

Comment: @KennethBruno actually, I wanna change all strings in certain array. The solution with or without regex. whichever is more fast.

Comment: How do you want to modify the strings?

Comment: @KennethBruno I updated my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it as follow:  `"\\bAB\\w+ZX\\b"`

```
var strings = ["AB_any_ZX","AB_whatever_ZX","HELLO"]

for (index, str) in strings.enumerate() {
    if let range = str.rangeOfString("\\bAB\\w+ZX\\b", options: .RegularExpressionSearch) {
        strings[index] = str.substringWithRange(range.startIndex.successor().successor()..<range.endIndex.predecessor().predecessor())

    }
}

print(strings)  // "["_any_", "_whatever_", "HELLO"]\n"
```

Comment: I wanna keep between AB and ZX. In your example I wanna keep the  _WHATEVER_ZX string. I just want replacing the string AB between and ZX with empty string ("") but keeping between AB and ZX

Comment: thats easy just use the range startIndex.successor().successor()

Comment: OK. It works. Sorry, I didn't see your comment. Swift is a new language why do you down vote?

Comment: I did not downvote. Usually if you don't post any code and or show some effort they downvote it

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for what you need?

```
import Foundation

var strings = ["AB111ZX","CD123EF","AB222ZX","A123ZX","AB123X","AB123","123ZX"]

strings = strings.flatMap {
  guard $0.hasPrefix("AB") && $0.hasSuffix("ZX") else { return nil }
  return $0.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "ABZX"))
}

print(strings)

// ["111","222"]
```

Comment: The string must replaced in array without using trim variable. I wanna apply this rule on the same array.

Comment: You mean you want to leave the other strings in the array alone and replace the found string with trimmed ones?

Comment: No.  (old) // var array1 = ["ABxxxZX", "ABasdZX"]  //  array1 = ["xxx", "asd"]